# OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount generates FOREIGN KEY constraint exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth

I've been trying for the past hours to add facebook login in my MVC 4 Website.

So far the 'local account registering' ( WebSecurity.CreateAccount() works perfectly.

In my businesslogic, my code looks like this:

```
public ValidationReturn<User> AddUser(User data, string provider, string providerUserId)
{
....

Repository.Insert(data);
SaveChanges();

OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount(provider, providerUserId, data.LoginName);
```

Right now, when I try to create a account like this, the OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount throw an exception:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.webpages_OAuthMembership_dbo.webpages_Membership_UserId". The
>   conflict occurred in database "Wims", table "dbo.webpages_Membership",
>   column 'UserId'.

I see my user in my UserTable, and I understand looking at the db scheme why it crashes... but I do not have any idea the reason... is OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount supposed to create a record in webpages_Membership as well? if so, what about the password?

I've been checking several tutorials on the web like this : 
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc, or http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/security/16-adding-security-and-membership
 and i don't see what i am missing here...

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i just found out... I use code first class that declare the structure of the tables created by the system when initializing the simplemembership... (because i needed to put the roles in a object to manage it from website)

example:

```
   [Table("webpages_OAuthMembership")]
    public class OAuthMembership
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 0), StringLength(30)]
        public string Provider { get; set; }

        [Key, Column(Order = 1), StringLength(100)]
        public string ProviderUserId { get; set; }

        public int UserId { get; set; }

        //[Column("UserId"), InverseProperty("OAuthMemberships")]
        //public Membership User { get; set; }
    }
```

Some of the FK were wrong..
jesus....

Hope it will help someone

Answer (score 0):

For me, I found that the code I had for the membership models had a Foreign Key on the OAuthMembership back to the Membership table. This was not correct, as you can have a OAuthMembership login, without  a local Membership record.
I had to comment out the lines below:

```
[Table("webpages_Membership")]
public class Membership
{
    public Membership()
    {
        Roles = new List<Role>();
        //OAuthMemberships = new List<OAuthMembership>();
    }

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string ConfirmationToken { get; set; }
    public bool? IsConfirmed { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastPasswordFailureDate { get; set; }
    public int PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(128)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PasswordChangedDate { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(128)]
    public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string PasswordVerificationToken { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PasswordVerificationTokenExpirationDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    //[ForeignKey("UserId")]
    //public ICollection<OAuthMembership> OAuthMemberships { get; set; }
}
```