# SimpleMembership provider & Foreign key contraint exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

I am trying to understand the SimpleMembershipProvider in detail. So far, I have created a new project in VWD-2012 with an empty Asp.Net MVC - 4 template.

I have been following [this great tutorial](http://blog.spontaneouspublicity.com/including-asp-net-simple-membership-tables-as-part-of-your-entity-framework-model). I was able to just copy and paste all the classes from this tutorial into my project. I then used the following line of code in my global.asax Application_Start method to initialize the SimpleMembershipProcider :

> WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("dbcontext", "UserProfile", "Id", "Name", true);

***(I am using Id and Name as a column name in my userprofile table)***

After that I enabled migration in my project, created the initial migration and then Update-Database. Then I check my database in visual studio and all classes related to SimipleMembership were formed.

Then I create a user and successfully logged in. Up to this point everything was working fine. I then added Facebook as an identity provider on my website. In this process when the code line

> OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount(provider, providerUserId, model.UserName);

trys to create an entry in webpages_OAuthMembership table. However the following exception was raised:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.webpages_OAuthMembership_dbo.webpages_Membership_UserId". The conflict occurred in database "dbcontext", table "dbo.webpages_Membership", column 'UserId'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Can anybody please help me solve this issue?

Comment: Here is a link to a related question regarding your OAuth membership errors. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068305/oauthwebsecurity-createorupdateaccount-generates-foreign-key-constraint-exceptio

Comment: @Nico i saw the link but i dont understand the answer provide on the link, can you please explain me ?